# laravel whereHas include no relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can i query relationship and still include models that has no relationships? There are two models

- Store
- Product

code

```
// Store
public function products() {
   $this->belongsToMany('App\Store');
}

// Product
public function stores() {
   $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

and a pivot table to connect them called `product_store`. Some stores don't have any products. How do i query all products, even those who doesn't belong to any store like:

`Product::where('store.id', '=', 1)->get()`

this is how i currently do it.

```
Product::whereHas('stores', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $store_id);
});
```

but as the [laravel docs mention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) this

> Retrieves all products with at least one store

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Product::doesntHave('stores')->orWhereHas('stores', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $store_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: how can i filter `$product->stores` to just one. ie the $store_id

Comment: this query gives you products of store with $store_id

Comment: yes. and it also gives me products that are not in any stores. but i also want products that are not in $store_id and in other stores

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Could you give me example?

Comment: suppose we have three products A, B, C. and two stores X & Y. A is available in X, B is available in Y, C is not available anywhere. if i run your query for X i am only getting A & C. but i want B too.

Comment: Product::all();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131475/discussion-between-bazi-and-alex-lukinov).